# UIButton tap not responding

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I added a new UIButton

```
    UIButton *newButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [newButton setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    [newButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [newButton setTag:x+INDEX_OFFSET];
    [newButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self addSubview:newButton];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:newButton];
```

and I can see it on the screen but it is not responding to a tap gesture. It should call "buttonPressed". Any help would be super!

Comment: Is this code in a view controller? If so, you want to add the button to self.view instead of self. Can you show the full code for your button handler?

Comment: @ShaggyFrog if this was the problem, again, it would have crashed the app with an unrecognized selector exception.

Comment: Can you see the button getting highlighted when you press it? If not, maybe there's a view obstructing the tap.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the possible problem is that you are adding the button in a frame position out its superview. Just to check it easily try to set `clipToBounds` property to YES in its superview bounds, then run the app. If you don't see the button it means that you set the button position out superivew position, that's why it doesn't respond to touches.

Comment: Yap that was it. Thank you. [self.superview addSubview:newButton]; solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible problem is if you add the `UIButton` as a `subview` to an `UIImageView` *(which you shouldn't, but it works)*. In this case, you could either add it to a `UIView` or set `UIImageView`'s `userInteractionEnabled` property to `YES`.